# Matching url path with regex in $urlRouterProvider.when()

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Based on the angular ui-router wiki (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider) it should be possible to use regex for matching the incoming path. How could I express regex to match following redirection rules:

```
$urlRouterProvider
  .when('', '/events')
  .when('/', '/events')
  .when('/:eventName', '/events/:eventName')
  .when('/results', '/events/results')
```

Test example:

```
localhost => localhost/#/events
localhost/ => localhost/#/events
localhost/myEvent => localhost/#/events/myEvent
localhost/results => localhost/#/events/results
localhost/#/events => localhost/#/events
localhost/#/results => localhost/#/results
```

Comment: And your issue is.... ?  You do know that `when()`s are designed to handle special cases... and `.state()`s are what is for handling the routing...  e.g. I want to use `events` instead of `e`...  "when" `/e` translate it to -> `/events`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the difference between urlRouterProvider and stateProvider. We are talking about the url redirection in this case, which later in the code will be mapped to specific state.

My question is how to define my redirection rules, explained in the first block in not working syntax?

Comment: Is it not working for you?  I do not see anything blatantly wrong...

Comment: This doesn't work. Failing example: localhost/events => localhost/events/events because 'events' is not ignored as the reserved path name

Comment: Shouldn't your test example above (last 2 ) be `localhost/events` vs `localhost/#/events `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer. Order of the when() statements and the state definition is important.

This works:

```
$urlRouterProvider
    .when('', '/events')
    .when('/', '/events')
    .when('/results', '/events/results')
$stateProvider
    .state('events', {
    ......
    }
$urlRouterProvider // This needs to be at the end to match all other matches
    .when('/:eventName', '/events/:eventName')
```