# How to skip param

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular ui-router

Here is my example route:

```
.state('collection.details', {
    url: '{id:[0-9]+}/?extra',
    views: {}
})
.state('collection.details.edit', {
    url: 'edit/',
    views: {}
})
```

For details I can have URL like this `app/2/?extra=true`but when I go to edit from that state I get url like this `app/2/edit/?extra=true` and I want to delete `?extra=true` so url looks like `app/2/edit/`. Is it possible? I don't want to lose nested route.

Comment: Use `$location.path()`. It returns the url stripped of query parameters. See [AngularJS $location API Reference -- path](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#path).

Answer (score 0):

### option 1: default route as add

treat the default state 'collection.details' as "add"

```
.state('collection.details', { //this state does add
    url: '{id:[0-9]+}/', 
    views: {}
})
.state('collection.details.edit', { //this state does edit
    url: 'edit/',
    views: {}
})
```

#### option 2: using $urlRouterProvider.when()

How about using "/add" instead of using "?add=true?
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094289/matching-url-path-with-regex-in-urlrouterprovider-when) explains more about regex on when()

```
//haven't tried this with regex before
$urlRouterProvider.when('{id:[0-9]+}/', '{id:[0-9]+}/add');

.state('collection.details', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '{id:[0-9]+}/',
    views: {}
})
.state('collection.details.add', {
    url: 'add/',
    views: {}
})
.state('collection.details.edit', {
    url: 'edit/',
    views: {}
})
```

Comment: `add` does not means `adding` only `additional info` :) my mistake. I do have separate state for adding. I edited to `extra`